# Html 5 Rotate image inside the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to rotate an image inside an canvas..I have googled and saw similar questions in stackoverflow.What i learnt is

1. I cannot rotate single object inside canvas.
2. I can rotate only thewhole canvas.
3. So i need to translate to center of the object and then rotate the
   canvas.

I Followed exactly same stuffs , But i am struck at translating to the image center..Below is the code i am using.Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J6Pfa/1/. This one is rotating the whole canvas regardless image..some one guide me where i am wrong.Thanks

```
//hero canvas
ball = new Hero();
var ang = 0;
herocanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
herocanvas.width =  herocanvas.width  = 500; 
herocanvas.height =  herocanvas.height = 500;
heroctx = herocanvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(herocanvas);


var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/WTgOHGg.png';
imgSprite.addEventListener('load',init,false);



function init()
{
startloop();
}

function startloop()
{
heroctx.save(); //saves the state of canvas
clearherobg() ; // clear canvas
heroctx.translate(ball.drawX, ball.drawY); //let's translate
heroctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (ang += 4)); 
ball.draw(); // draw image here
heroctx.restore();
requestAnimFrame(startloop);
}   
function Hero() {
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 500;
    this.drawX = 220;
    this.drawY = 200;
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 40;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.isUpKey = false;
    this.isRightKey = false;
    this.isDownKey = false;
    this.isLeftKey = false;

}

Hero.prototype.draw = function () {
  heroctx.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
};

function clearherobg() {
    heroctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
}
```

Those who cannot read full code ..Please check `startloop()` , thats the main infinite loop..`ball.drawX and ball.drawY` are the x and y position of image inside canvas

Comment: Hero's drawX and drawY need to be updated to new coordinate system of canvas, if u want it to be in the middle of canvas it needs to be 0,0.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/J6Pfa/3/

Comment: thanks tomasz working.. can you answer it ? so i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hero's drawX and drawY need to be updated to new coordinate system of canvas, if u want it to be in the middle of canvas it needs to be 0,0.

Something like this: jsfiddle.net/J6Pfa/3

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i dont exactly understand what you want to achieve, an image moving on the circle path ? or having image in one place, and just rotate it  ?

Comment: image in one place and just rotate it

Comment: Do you have to do it by html5 ? the easier solutuin is to use css3 i guess. This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hnc8/) example, on hover. I dont know if you need it to be rotated always, or not, however this code can be use for anything you wish

Comment: if u want to make it rotate all the time u can use something like that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/)

Comment: thanks for css..but i need in html bro..+1 for your comments though

Comment: okey check [this](http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-rotate-html5-canvas-around-center/) maybe, however it uses a lil java